# random.randint for non integer number? [Python]

Tags: python, random

How can I make a random number between something like 0.1 to 0.9 ?

randint only work for integer numbers =/

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [random.uniform()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform).  For your example, `random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)`.

It's equivalent to using random.random() to get a value between 0.0 and 1.0, then scaling and shifting the value appropriately:

```
def rand_float_range(start, end):
    return random.random() * (end - start) + start
```

Comment: The above is a good answer, but also take a look at numpy.random 

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

Comment: +1: Never knew that was there.  Way better than my trivialized "just multiply randint by a floating point number" answer, and it's about 3 times faster.